# Unhook Func Target

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a Dictionary of byte[], Func as below:

```
 public class ImageSizeReader : IDisposable
 {

    private Dictionary<byte[], Func<BinaryReader, Size>> imageFormatDecoders;

    public ImageSizeReader()
    {
        imageFormatDecoders = new Dictionary<byte[], Func<BinaryReader, Size>>()
        {
            { new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4D }, DecodeBitmap },
            { new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x61 }, DecodeGif },
            { new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 }, DecodeGif },
            { new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }, DecodePng },
            { new byte[] { 0xff, 0xd8 }, DecodeJfif }};
    }

    private Size DecodeBitmap(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
    ....
    }

    private Size DecodeGif(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
        ...
    }

    private Size DecodePng(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
      ...
    }

    private Size DecodeJfif(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
       ...
    }

}
```

After using Memory Profiler I notice that this Dictionary is preventing garbage collection on it's parent class:

[image]

I am assuming it is because the Func delegate is still wired up. How would I 'unhook' this delegate list correctly?

Comment: is `imageFormatDecoders` static?

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White, I have updated the code sample. The imageFormatDecoders is an instance member.

Comment: As an aside, byte[] makes a terrible dictionary key unless you override the comparer because equality is based on reference equality.

Comment: Sure it is keeping the instance alive, but the instance is also the only thing keeping the dictionary alive. They form a cycle and the GC knows how to handle those. Once all external references to the decoder are released it will be collectible because it is not reachable from a GC root, not because there are no references to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this and eventually found that the code in the image above was compiler generated from a linq statement:

```
int maxMagicBytesLength = imageFormatDecoders.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First().Length;
```

I removed this method and did the same in a foreach loop which resolved the issue.